# Apache Spark: Hold Custom class in GraphX: Not Serializable?

Tags: scala, class, serialization, apache-spark

I have an article class

```
case class Article(articleName:String,
                   id:Option[Long],
                    authors: Iterator[Author],
                    keywords: Iterator[String])
```

(Author is a class that holds 4 options of strings)

and I want to create a graph out of it. I created an RDD of vertices and an RDD of edges

```
val vertices: RDD[(VertexId, Article)] = articles.map(article => (article.id.get , article))
```

when I create my graph:

```
val graph = Graph(vertices, edges)
```

I get the following error (shortened):

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: scala.collection.LinearSeqLike$$anon$1
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
```

I'm not sure I understand why I can't do what I am doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class is not serializable because a `LinearSeqLike` in it is not serializable. Tasks that run on spark cluster nodes have to be serialized to get there. I'd suggest using `List` or some other such concrete, serializable sequence type rather than `Iterator`.

Comment: If I use a list, it seems that in my code I am losing all the nice capabilities I use to construct my graph, such as map, filter, etc. I'll look into workarounds...

Comment: You can construct the `Iterator` as you currently do and just do one `toList` at the end. (That said, I'm not quite sure what your complaint is, because `List` supports `map`, `filter` and so on). You need a fixed value to send across the cluster, not some lazy computed-on-demand `Iterator`, for reasons that are hopefully obvious. (If the `authors` and `keywords` are very large sets, you could turn them into `RDD`s and then `zip` or `product` or `join` those with your other RDDs) rather than trying to include them in a case class.